# Как отключить повторный вызов OnCreate при смене ориентации экрана

Tags: android, android-manifest

В `OnCreate` при запуске приложения вызывается `fragment1` с `TextView1` с текстом. Есть `button`, который переключает на другой фрагмент - `fragment2` с `TextView2` и текстом в нем. Так вот, если нажать на `button`, переключится на `fragment2`. Но если перевернуть смартфон - переключится на горизонтальную ориентацию и поверх `TextView2`, как бы на заднем фоне, откроется `TextView1`. Если вернуть обратно, то еще больше наслоится.

Я так понимаю, при смене ориентации экрана, `Android` заново вызывает `OnCreate`. Как запретить это? Но при этом, чтобы ничего не менялось кроме ориентации. То есть, если я нажал на `button` и читаю `TextView2`, чтобы при смене ориентации я остался в этом же фрагменте с этим же `TextView2`?

Прописал в Манифесте:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Но не помогло. Возможно, нужно еще что-то добавить, или вовсе это неправильно. Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему.

Comment: вызов onCreate в любом случае будет после смены ориентации. Вам нужно просто в OnCreate делать проверку. Читайте в сторону savedinstance.

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы вам помогли, прикладывайте проблемный код. Могу предположить, что вы добавляете фрагменты методом `add()`, поэтому происходит наслоение. Добавляйте их методом `replace()` и сохраняйте состояние при изменениях конфигурации, чтобы потом можно было восстановить его.

Comment: Мне казалось я изъяснил понятно. Дело не в фрагментах. Добавляю я методом replace(). Все отлично работает. Проблема в ориентации.

Comment: @Алексей, при повороте экрана активити в любом случае пересоздастся, вам просто нужно сохранить состояние и обработать его при пересоздании. в интернете много информации, попробуйте поискать (например "сохранение фрагментов при повороте экрана"), прежде чем задавать вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема решена. Все гораздо проще)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема решена. Вот решение для тех, кто столкнется с такой же проблемой. Надеюсь и Вам поможет.

Я добавил в `AndroidManifest.xml` строчку

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Добавлять её нужно в `<activity>`!

Получается так:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```